# How to create a Doughnut chart in windows 8 app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, charts, winrt-xaml, modern-ui

I am using the excellent [Modern](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) UI Charts for creating a Doughnut chart in my Windows 8 application. But I haven't been able to customize it much which has led me to look for other ways to create a doughnut chart. I would be very happy if anyone could answer my below questions on how to customize the Modern UI chart or if not then please do suggest on how i can implement my own Doughnut chart or any other FREE library which i can use to implement it.

Customizability questions on Modern UI charts:

1. How to increase the size of the Doughnut chart ? (**Major Issue**)
2. How to show percentages instead of numbers on the chart ? I know I can calculate the percentages and pass them to the chart but I will still not see the "%" symbol on the UI which will confuse the user as to whether the numbers are actual statistic number of percentages (**Minor Issue**)
3. Is there any way I can show the legend items vertically rather than horizantally ? (**Minor Issue**)

I would be happy if atleast I can increase the size of the chart otherwise I will have to look at a totally new way to create doughnut charts. Any lead or help on creating doughnut charts will be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You should be able to set the size of the chart. What have you tried that hasn't worked? Based on my reading of the sample [`Generic.xaml`](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ModernUIChart/TestApplication.WinRT/Themes/Generic.xaml) you can set an arbitrary height and width in the chart style.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should be able to set the size of the chart. Try changing the chart style. If it's a larger PlottedArea that you want, the styles for those are in there as well.

2) You should be able to change the style for the `PiePieceLabel`. You can either set one for a given control or all over. Below is an example for setting it globally.

```
<Style TargetType="charts:PiePieceLabel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charts:PiePieceLabel">
                <Border>
                    <!-- Changed it to a StackPanel -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Value}" />
                        <!-- May need a margin -->
                        <TextBlock Text="%" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

3) Yes. Same deal. Find the Legend style. Change it to display vertically.